# I want m cell to be "-" this if n cell has any text other than "delivered"

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft

I want m cell to be "-" this if n cell has any text other than "delivered" ... And need this m cell blank if n cell has "delivered"

Comment: Do you know about the existence of [**Help**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2)? Or is it easier for you to ask Superuser and wait three hours for an answer? Can you apply the ***For example, =IF(C2=”Yes”,1,2) says IF(C2 = Yes, then return a 1, otherwise return a 2)*** string to your needs on your own?

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula in **Column M**:

```
=IF(N1="delivered","","-")
```

[image]